# Chrome's DevTools console scroll

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to save my Chrome's DevTools console history. 
I know I can right-click "Save log as", but this only goes to up to the last clear. 
I could just never clear console, but then I'm annoyingly stuck working off the bottom of the screen.
Is there anyway to scroll the console screen?

Comment: Scrolling works fine for me on macOS High Sierra. What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can't but there is a filter field top of the console, just put some random text in it, and it is hide all the logs for you.